# Computing $\pi_2$ of some 2-complex.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $m$ be a positive integer and $F_m$ be the free group on $m$ generators.

Choose an element $\gamma\in F_m$.

Then, there is a loop $\overline{\gamma}\colon S^1\to \vee_{i=1}^m S^1$ such that $\gamma=[\overline{\gamma}]\in \pi_1(\vee_{i=1}^mS^1)=F_m$.

Let $X_\gamma=\vee_{i=1}^m S^1\cup_{\overline{\gamma}} D^2$ be the space obtained by attaching a 2-cell to $\vee_{i=1}^mS^1$ along $\overline{\gamma}$.

**Question:**I would like to prove that if $\gamma\neq 0\in F_m$, then $\pi_2(X_\gamma)=0$.

If $\gamma=1$, then $X_\gamma=S^2\vee(\vee_{i=1}^mS^1)$. So, $\pi_2(X_\gamma)=\mathbb{Z}[F_m]$ as $\mathbb{Z}[F_m]$-module.

In this case, $F_m=\pi_1(X_\gamma)$.

I know that $\pi_2(X_\gamma)=H_2(\tilde{X_\gamma})$ where $p\colon \tilde{X_\gamma}\to X_\gamma$  is the universal cover of $X_\gamma$.

But, I could not analyse the boundary map $C_2(\tilde{X_\gamma})\to C_1(\tilde{X_\gamma})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Let $m=1$. Let $\gamma$ be the square of a generator. Then $X_\gamma$ is $\mathbb{RP}^2$.